# Java runtime.exec() running multiple process using Threadpool

Tags: java, maven, runtime.exec

In my program I have a list of n  test scripts , I need to iterate the list and run 3 test scripts in parallel. To achieve this task I created a Threadpool of size 3. My implementation is like below for the thread pool

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);
for (int threadpoolCount = 0; threadpoolCount < classNames.size(); threadpoolCount++) {
    Runnable worker = new ProcessRunnable(classNames.get(threadpoolCount));
    executor.execute(worker);
}
executor.shutdown();
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
}

System.out.println("Finished all threads");
```

below is my thread implementation where in i execute a batch file with maven commands in it

```java
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println(testname);
        System.out.println("Task ID : " + this.testname + " performed by " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /C Junit_runner.bat" + " " + testname);
        p.waitFor();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Here is what I get in my console (I am not starting the command prompt and running it in background)

**com.selenium.test.testname1
Task ID : com.selenium.test.testname1 
performed by pool-1-thread-1**

**com.selenium.test.testname1
Task ID : com.selenium.test.testname2
performed by pool-1-thread-2**

**com.selenium.test.testname1
Task ID : com.selenium.test.testname3
performed by pool-1-thread-3**

The execution pauses here and it didn't do anything , I am not sure what's happening behind. I also cross checked that the batch file its working fine.

Comment: How long does it take for `Junit_runner.bat` take to run?

Comment: Its take 2 to 3 minutes to complete its executions and termiante , her e is my batch file command  . **@Echo off

echo %1

call mvn -f pom.xml test -Dtest=%1

exit**

Answer (score 2):

The process takes **long** to execute and so your control is not returning back.

```
public abstract int waitFor() throws InterruptedException
```

Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the process represented by this Process object has terminated. This method returns immediately if the subprocess has already terminated. If the subprocess has not yet terminated, the calling thread will be blocked until the subprocess exits.

As `waitFor()` is a blocking call all the 3 threads are stuck at this line.

**NOTE:** You don't need `Thread.sleep(5000);` as `waitFor()` is itself blocking in nature.

Try executing some other command and see if the control returns.

Also instead of:

```
while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
}
```

You can use [ExecutorService#awaitTermination()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29)

Comment: forget to mention , if i kill the execution after its getting blocked , the batch file starts for all the  three thread .

Comment: @user2644818 I didn't get you can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: as i have posted in my question once the execution starts initiating three process and pauses for long time , post killing the execution the batch file which i call from Runtime.exec("") starts

Comment: Thanks for your inputs , i have no idea on wat else command to be used apart from waitfor() , any idea on it ?

Comment: @Vigneshwaran I am suggesting you to fire some other command such as `cmd cd ..` in the process `exec()` instead of using your batch file that you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Read the p.getInputStream() and p.getErrorStream() and write it to your console instead of thread.sleep(), you will get an indication of what the threads are doing.